# Hexagonal rooks

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose you have a triangular chessboard of size $n$, whose "squares" are ordered triples $(x,y,z)$ of nonnegative integers that add up to $n$.  A rook can move to any other point that agrees with it in one coordinate -- for example, if you are on $(3,1,4)$ then you can move to $(2,2,4)$ or to $(6,1,1)$, but not to $(4,3,1)$.

What is the maximum number of mutually non-attacking rooks that can be placed on this chessboard?

More generally, is anything known about the graph whose vertices are these ordered triples and whose edges are rook moves?

Comment: Can you prove what the maximal number of mutually non-attacking bishops is on an ordinary n×n chessboard? 

Comment: The bishop question is easy - it's 2n-2.  Put bishops along two opposite edges and remove two at adjacent corners.  This is maximal since there are only 2n-1 different North-East diagonals, and two of these are opposite corners so only 2n-2 can be filled.

Comment: The graph is regular, of degree $2n$. If you put a rook on $(n,0,0)$, the problem reduces to finding the maximum number of non-attacking rooks on the board of order $n-2$. I think the graph has enough symmetry that no matter where you put the first rook you reduce the problem to that of order $n-2$, but I'm not sure. If the graph does have that symmetry, then by induction you get more-or-less $n/2$ rooks ($(n+2)/2$ if $n$ is even, $(n+1)/2$ if $n$ is odd). 

Comment: That's a nice idea, but I don't think it works. If you remove (2,1,0) from $G_3$, you get a path of length $3$, not a cycle.

Comment: I can prove the upper bound $3(n+2)(n+1)/(4n)$: Each rook threatens $2n$ "square"s, but each of the $(n+2)(n+1)/2$ squares may only be threatened $3$ times. 

Comment: In particular, the rook placement $(2,1,0)$, $(1,0,2)$, $(0,2,1)$ for $n=3$ is better then the bound $(3+1)/2$ that Gerry proposes. I can't figure out how to generalize that example, though.

Comment: Isn't $n+1$ an upper bound because no two of the rooks can agree on the first coordinate?

Comment: One of the coordinates must have an average value of no more than $n/3$ among all the rooks. The maximal number of distinct nonnegative integers whose avergae is $n/3$ is $2n/3+1$. This is a better bound.

Comment: Only loosely related: there's been an extensive study of simplicial complexes called chessboard complexes whose i-dimensional faces are the collections of i+1 nonattacking rooks on a chessboard.  Now you make me curious about hexagonal chessboard complexes.  The traditional chessboard complexes actually have come up in quite a few different contexts and have all sorts of torsion, etc. 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a paper about this problem: ["Non-attacking queens on a triangle"](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~pcp/nonattacking_queens.pdf).

And here's another one ["Putting Dots in Triangles"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.4325)

Comment: Good references.
The first paper (Nivasch-Lev, *Mathematics Magazine* 2005) ends up giving another proof of the $\lfloor 2n/3 \rfloor + 1$ bound,
and the same construction to attain this bound.


Comment: Cristi, thanks!  I didn't know about either of these references.

Comment: An earlier reference is Problem 131 in *Which Way Did the Bicycle Go?*, Konhauser, Velleman, and Wagon (1996).

Answer (score 14):

Nice question!

For the maximum number of pairwise non-defending rooks,
Will Sawin proved an upper bound of $(2n/3) + 1$
in his comment to the original question.  This bound is attained,
at least to within $O(1)$, by two rows of $n/3 - O(1)$ rooks each,
starting from around $(2n/3,n/3,0)$ and $(n/3,2n/3,1)$
and proceeding by steps of $(-1,-1,2)$ until reaching the
$y=0$ or $x=0$ edge of the triangle.  This construction
generalizes Sawin's five-Rook placement for $n=6$.

On further thought, it seems we actually achieve
$\lfloor (2n/3) + 1 \rfloor$ exactly for all $n$.
Here's how it works for $n=12$ and $n=15$, 
with $(2n/3)+1 = 9$ and $11$ respectively:

```
                                            .   
                                           . . 
                                          . . . 
            .                            . . . . 
           . .                          . . . . . 
          . . .                        R . . . . . 
         . . . .                      . . . . . . R 
        R . . . .                    . R . . . . . . 
       . . . . . R                  . . . . . . . R . 
      . R . . . . .                . . R . . . . . . . 
     . . . . . . R .              . . . . . . . . R . . 
    . . R . . . . . .            . . . R . . . . . . . . 
   . . . . . . . R . .          . . . . . . . . . R . . . 
  . . . R . . . . . . .        . . . . R . . . . . . . . . 
 . . . . . . . . R . . .      . . . . . . . . . . R . . . . 
. . . . R . . . . . . . .    . . . . . R . . . . . . . . . .
```

Starting from such a solution with $n=3m$, we can add an empty row 
to get an optimal solution for $n=3m+1$, and remove an edge
(and the Rook it contains) to get an optimal solution for $n=3m-1$.
So this should solve the problem for all $n$.

Jeremy Martin also asks:

> More generally, is anything known about the graph whose vertices
>   are these ordered triples and whose edges are rook moves?

I don't remember reading about this graph before.
Experimentally (for $3 \leq n \leq 16$) its adjacency matrix
has all eigenvalues integral, the smallest being $-3$ with huge multiplicity
$n-1\choose 2$; more precisely:

> **Conjecture.** For $n \geq 3$ the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix are:
>   a simple eigenvalue at the graph degree $2n$; a $n-1\choose 2$-fold
>   eigenvalue at $-3$; and a triple eigenvalue at each integer
>   $\lambda \in [-2,n-2]$, except that $\mu := \lfloor n/2 \rfloor - 2$
>   is omitted, and $\mu - (-1)^n$ has multiplicity only $2$.

This is probably not too hard to show.  For example, the $\lambda = -3$
eigenvectors constitute the codimension-$3n$ space of functions
whose sum over each of the $3(n+1)$ Rook lines vanishes.
*[Added later: in the comment Jeremy Martin reports that
he and Jennifer Wagner already made* **and proved** *the same conjecture.]*

Given that the minimal eigenvalue is $-3$,
it follows by a standard argument in "spectral graph theory"
that the maximal cocliques have size at most $3(n+1)(n+2)/(4n+6) = 3n/4 + O(1)$.
But that's asymptotically worse than $2n/3 + O(1)$, though it's still
good enough to prove the optimality of Will Sawin's cocliques of size
$5$ for $n=6$ and of size $7$ for $n=9$.

Here's some **gp** code to play with this graph and its spectrum:

```
{
R(n)=
  l = [];
  for(a=0,n,for(b=0,n-a,l=concat(l,[[a,b,n-a-b]])));
  matrix(#l,#l,i,j,vecmin(abs(l[i]-l[j]))==0) - 1
}
```

running "R($n$)" puts a list of the vertices in "l" and returns
the adjacency matrix with the corresponding labeling.  So for instance

```
matkerint(R(7)-2)~
matkerint(R(8)-1)~
```

returns matrices whose rows are nice generators of the
$2$-dimensional eigenspaces of the $n=7$ and $n=8$ graphs.

Comment: Noam, you've scooped me! :-)  Jennifer Wagner and I have recently proved this conjecture by giving an explicit basis of eigenvectors.  Writeup forthcoming.  (Even more generally, we conjecture that the "simplicial rook graph" --- put a vertex at each lattice point in the $n$th dilate of the standard simplex in $\mathbb{R}^d$; edges are pairs of vertices at Hamming distance 2 -- has integer eigenvalues.)

Corollary: the independence number of the triangular rook graph is at most $3(n+2)(n+1)/(2(2n+3))$.  But, indeed, this bond is not tight.

Back to the independence question: it appears tha

Comment: Seems like your comment was cut off by the 600-character limit.  Anyway, it's not really a "scoop" since I only conjectured it
(though I see that the lower bound of $-3$ on the spectrum is not hard, and likewise for your generalization to higher dimension).

Comment: I was going to ask about the independence number about the higher-dimensional simplicial rook graph.  The computational evidence I have suggests that the least eigenvalue is $\min(-n,-\binom{d}{2})$.  E.g., for $d=4$, $n\geq 6$, this would imply that the independence number $\alpha(n)$ is at most $a(n)=\lfloor(n+1)(n+3)/3\rfloor$.  This is not a tight bound (e.g., $a(6)=21$, $\alpha(6)=16$) and I would guess that it is not even asymptotically tight.

Comment: The eigenvalue bound (which you probably mean to be
$\max(-n,-{d\choose 2})$, not $\min$) can be proved
in the same way, by writing the adjacency matrix
as the sum of $d\choose 2$ adjacency matrices (one for each direction)
each with minimal eigenvalue $-1$.

Answer (score 7):

A visualization aid, $n=10$:

          
[image: HexChess n=10]

And now here are Will Swain's rook placements:

[image: HexRooks n=6,5][image: HexRooks n=9,7]

Answer (score 6):

For n=6 you can fit 5 rooks

(0,2,4)
(4,0,2)
(1,4,1)
(3,3,0)
(2,1,3)

For n=9 you can fit 7 rooks

(0,3,6)
(6,0,3)
(2,6,1)
(4,5,0)
(3,1,5)
(5,2,2)
(1,4,4)

Answer (score 2):

This has a connection with additive permutations, asked about here:
[Are there enough additive permutations?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/211276) .

http://oeis.org/A002047 has references to a similar problem involving a hexagonal board and counting the number of placements. (The Bennett and Potts reference calls the piece a 'brook'.) This number also counts the permutations.  A recent ArXiv paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.05987 appears to provide an asymptotic estimate.  Note that placement on a hexagonal board gives one for the triangle, but there may be placements in a triangle corner that are not realizable in the hexagon.

Gerhard "Cutting Corners For More Results" Paseman, 2017.03.13